# Scrapy ignore pages with http auth

Tags: scrapy, basic-authentication

Is there a way or setting in [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to ignore pages having an basic http authentication while the crawling is in progress.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'ignore pages', do you want to ignore the requests or the response? Also the page doesn't use a 401, 503, other than 200 code?

Comment: I want to ignore the requests made for pages having an http auth. Currently I am using the approach to check the link header for www-authenticate but no idea if there is a better approach